# Reading XML in a procedure for select query

Tags: mysql, xml, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure in which I am passing a xml type data. I am trying to read that data but it is always giving null.

```
delimiter //
create procedure SP_LogIn(xml text)
begin
declare AgentId varchar(30);
declare pass varchar(30);
set @AgentId=ExtractValue(@xml,'/operation/userName');
set @Pass=ExtractValue(@xml,'/operation/paasword');
select * from am_agentmasteraccount where am_AgentId=@AgentId and am_AgentPassword=@Pass;
end //
delimiter;
```

here I am calling the procedure

```
call SP_Login('<operation><userName>RAJ0560111</userName><password>rajpratha</password></operation>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it would work.

```
delimiter //
create procedure SP_LogIn(xml text)
begin
declare AgentId varchar(30);
declare pass varchar(30);
set AgentId:=(ExtractValue(xml,'/operation/userName'));
set Pass:=(ExtractValue(xml,'/operation/password'));
select * from am_agentmasteraccount where am_AgentId=AgentId and am_AgentPassword=Pass;
select AgentId,pass;
end //
delimiter;
```